# Как javascript работает с таймаутами (setTimeout, setInterval)?

Tags: javascript

Интересует именно куда эти таймауты помещаются, как очищаются. А также где хранится информация о том, когда их нужно выполнить.

Как я понимаю, все точно также как с функциями. Т.е. помещаются в стек вызова, а очищаются с помощью сборщика мусора. Или нет? Помогите разобраться.

Comment: А с какой целью вы интерисуетесь?

Comment: Найдите исходники браузера... гугл какойто  "открытый" вроде клепает.

Comment: JavaScript сам с тайм-аутами не работает и работать не умеет и не может уметь. Native-компонент, написаный, вероятнее всего на с++, для IE это ActiveX/COM подключен к javascipt своеобразным шлюзом. Как реализован, не знаю, но на с++ есть всего две реализации таймера 1)оконный таймер [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906%28VS.85%29.aspx), и системный таймер [CreateWaitableTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682492(v=vs.85).aspx). Ещё есть изврат с засеканием времени, а так же WaitForSingleObject,  через которые можно реализовать таймер на с++.

Comment: @nick_n_a Интерес с целью разобраться. Был такой вопрос на собеседовании.
Речь идет про setTimeout, setInterval. (https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval).

Comment: По вашей ссылке все хорошо описано. От себя могу разве что добавить... по идее, нужно вывести на экран что вернула функция. Думаю... это число. Тут два варианта, либо используется "сквозная нумерация", либо даются "хандлы" которые потом повторно используются. Скорее всего после перезагрузки страницы память о таймауте обнуляется. Возможно https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout материал от фокса (и внизу их станицы ещё ссылки) чем-то поможет.

Comment: Теоретически, информация о таймере должна занимать не более 16 байт. Очищать или нет уборщиком мусора - впринципе если таймер работает - не очищать пока не сделают clear, а таймаут - я бы чистил... только всё это при условии что выданный номер можно "признать" недействительным (сквозной). Если номера выданные setTimeout и setInterval повторяются - то можно сказать что уборщик мусора работает.

Comment: А браузеры, у них уже появился доступ к уборщику мусора? Он спрятан, и реально увидеть его работу... думаю сложно.

Comment: @nick_n_a Спасибо за ваши ответы. К сожалению, в статье по ссылке я так и не нашел ответы на свои вопросы. Поэтому и задал их здесь.
Насчет очистки ничего не могу сказать, пока не ясно, где и как эти таймауты хранятся.

Comment: Для браузеров есть [спецификация на таймеры](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#timers) для других сред, например nodejs, и поведение и реализация могу отличаться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут все очень наглядно изложено: [Про цикл событий в JavaScript или "как на самом деле работает асинхронность"?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cV4ZvHXQL4&t=210s)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Это то, что нужно.